# How can I design separate invoice email template for buyer and seller and email gets send them accordingly?

Tags: email-templates, order-email

Currently, when customer place the order, buyer and site admin gets the same order/invoice email design. I want different design of email template for customer and admin. I am not sure whether we can do that in Magento or not. Can anyone help me out how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Buyer and Seller" tells me custom module... which means you'll need a custom module for your email templates.

Comment: what do you mean by seller? to the admin?

Comment: Yes. Customer and Site Owner. Both gets same design mail on order placed. I want to modify design for Site Owner. How that can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is quite a long conversation and for that i am pasting the following link hoping to give a hint on how to achieve what you want,
[customizing magento email tamplates](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates).
I also suggest to buy/download a book in order to increase your skills.

Comment: Sorry. Didnt helped. I have already gone through that web page.